# Why is the singleton class an instance of itself?

Tags: ruby

The question is quite hard to word. All objects have a singleton class (aka ghost class) which is a class on which we can define methods just for that object.

But when we inspect the singleton class we see it is an instance of a class which are both he same object.

```
o = Object.new
o.singleton_class.instance_eval { self.object_id } # => 47082984969880
o.singleton_class.class_eval { self.object_id } # => 47082984969880
```

This is because the singleton class is an anonymous class.

```
o.singleton_class # => #<Class:#<Object:0x0000557ed623d8b8>>
o.singleton_class.name # => nil
```

An anonymous class is a class of type `Class`

```
o.singleton_class.class # => Class
```

And the class of `Class` is `Class`:

```
Class.class # => Class
Class.new.class == Class # => true
```

`Class` is an instance of itself.

Thus we can see that the singleton class is an an anonymous class of type `Class`, they are the same instance of `Class`

```
Class.object_id # => 47001622014720
o.singleton_class.class.object_id # => 47001622014720
```

But why using `class_eval` and `instance_eval` do we get the same objects, but looking at the instance and class without eval we do not?

```
o.singleton_class.instance_eval { self.object_id } # => 47082984969880
o.singleton_class.class_eval { self.object_id }    # => 47082984969880
o.singleton_class.object_id                        # => 47082984969880
o.singleton_class.class.object_id                  # => 47001622014720
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are getting 47001622014720 from o.singleton_class.class.object_id is really the same as Class.object_id which should also yield 47001622014720.

Take this a step further and try ancestors instead of object_id to see if you can get more understanding of what is going on.

```
o.singleton_class.instance_eval { self.ancestors } # => [#<Class:#<Object:0x00007f9b3c0465d0>>, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
o.singleton_class.class_eval { self.ancestors }    # => [#<Class:#<Object:0x00007f9b3c0465d0>>, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
o.singleton_class.ancestors # => [#<Class:#<Object:0x00007f9b3c0465d0>>, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
o.singleton_class.class.ancestors # => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: "Metapgramming Ruby" by Paolo Perrotta is great book is goes into your question in great detail.